# SQL Server - id primary key not auto incrementing

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a simple table within an sql server containing the following:

- id (int) - primary key (identity specification: Yes, Identity Increment:1)
- FirstName - varchar (50)
- LastName - varchar (50)
- email - varchar(50)

I've setup the html form below to insert data into this very simple table which is presenting the following error:

```
<?php

require ('connect.inc.php');

if(ISSET($_POST['FirstName'])&&ISSET($_POST['LastName'])&&ISSET($_POST['email'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['FirstName'])&&!empty($_POST['LastName'])&&!empty($_POST['email'])){
        $FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
        $LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $sql_insert = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT test.dbo.clients ON
                INSERT INTO test.dbo.clients (id, FirstName, LastName, email) 
                VALUES('', '$FirstName', '$LastName', '$email')";
        $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM test.dbo.clients";
        $sql_insert_query = odbc_exec($con, $sql_insert);       
        }
    else{
        echo "Please input fields";
        }
}
else{
    echo "Not set";
}

/*$sql = "INSERT INTO clients ()
        VALUES ()"
*/
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <table border="2">
            <form action="inputform.php" method="POST">
                <tr>
                    <td>First name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="FirstName"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last name:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="LastName"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>e-mail:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"></td>
                </tr>
            </form> 
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The error below indicates that the id (PK), is not automincrementing:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_clients'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.clients'.

Attached is an image showing how the id key is configured.

Thanks in advance.
J[image]

Comment: That's what "SET IDENTITY_INSERT test.dbo.clients ON" does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're trying to insert the identity value manually.  Note where you enable that:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT test.dbo.clients ON
```

And note your `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO test.dbo.clients (id, FirstName, LastName, email) 
VALUES('', '$FirstName', '$LastName', '$email')
```

The database engine will provide an auto-increment identity, *unless you tell it not to*.  Which is what you're doing.  Inserting an empty string into a numeric column, inserting an empty primary key, etc. are all pretty bad ideas.

If you want the database to provide the identity, then don't provide one in your code:

```
INSERT INTO test.dbo.clients (FirstName, LastName, email) 
VALUES('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$email')
```

---

Also, please note that your code is ***highly vulnerable*** to [SQL injection attacks](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).  You're going to want to make use of prepared statements.  As it stands, you're currently allowing users to *execute their own code* on your server.

Comment: Thank you @David. I know it's vulnerable; I've only just started learning some development, and I'm only testing. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

not much into php. but change this line & let sql handle the identity key values..

```
 $sql_insert = "
                INSERT INTO test.dbo.clients (FirstName, LastName, email) 
                VALUES('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$email')";
```